# Struggling with onclick in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, php

I work for a hire company, and I decided paperwork was a pain and have started putting it online instead. I'm building a service/repair database to store records and information on machines on our fleet. We have a desktop pc in the workshop, connected to the internet, but we have had an ongoing issue with our phone lines dropping in and out for the last few years and despite us calling out engineers, they can't explain it. Anyway, long story short, I've made a 'backup' copy of the website and database on localhost using xampp. I made a simple script to detect if we were online or not and added it to an onclick event.

```
function conchecklink(link) {
    var online = navigator.onLine;
    var livelink = "http://www.example.com/workshop/" + link;
    var locallink = "http://localhost/workshop/" + link; 

    if (online == true) {
      window.location(livelink);
    }
    if (online == false) {
      window.location(locallink);
    } 
}
```

For each href on the website I am using this:

```
<a onclick=\"conchecklink('service.php')\" href=\"#\"> Service</a>
<a onclick=\"conchecklink('repair.php')\" href=\"#\"> Repairs</a>
```

Now this works absolutely fine on desktop, when internet drops out, it redirects to localhost, and visa versa. But when viewing on my mobile, the onclick event doesn't fire. From googling this, I understand I should be using ontouch for mobile, I tried a few things I found in my search, but alas I am only a mechanic, not a professional coder and I can't get the links working on mobile. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use .on() jQuery method.

Comment: And by the way onclick events do fire on mobile devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error: `window.location` is not a function. On your mobile, the browser should throw an error and stops the script. Your desktop browser seems to be more conciliant.

You also could use `else` instead of using two `if` statements.

```
function conchecklink(link) {
    var online = navigator.onLine;
    var livelink = "http://www.example.com/workshop/" + link;
    var locallink = "http://localhost/workshop/" + link; 
    if (online) window.location.href = livelink;
    else window.location.href = locallink;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much, works perfectly now. Like I said im only a mechanic and self taught code so knowledge is usually google based!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have used window.location is wrong, it is not a function hence do not accept arguments.
you can use it like this window.location = URL;